# Grant permissions to resource in one subscription to application from another subscription? (Azure AD multitenant apps)

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have resource in Azure subscription #1 and I want to grant permissions to Azure AD application from subscription #2. Both subscription have separate AAD tenants.

I've created application in subscription #2, marked it as multi-tenant and added certificate credentials to it. There're a few instructions on how to create multi-tenant apps that can login users from multiple tenants. But I don't need any of these logins and don't want to host any API for it. All I need is for users in other subscriptions being able to grant my app permissions to the resources.

I can't figure out how can I link (give consent) to app from another subscription/AAD tenant. My understanding there should be a way for me to reference AppId from app in subscription #2 and create new service principal for it unders subscription #1.

I've tried in subscription #1 `New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId <AppIdFromSubscription2>`

Fails with "Code: Request_ResourceNotFound, Message: Resource 'ServicePrincipal_888ad8a8-8888-4652-8b8b-c141fa1e7191' does not exist or one of its queried
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New-AzureADServicePrincipal with AppId from another subscription does work.

I had silly mistake on my end, I've been using my @outlook.com account for my subscription and Connect-AzureAD logged me under some MSA tenant, which I have no permissions to modify. Once I specified TenantId with Connect-AzureAD, New-AzureADServicePrincipal worked fine.